# What kind of sensitive information gdm log files may contain?

Tags: security, gdm

ubuntu-bug warns me about including gdm log files since they may contain sensitive information. Can you be more specific what kind of sensitive information these files may contain?

Answer (score 1):

These logs store output of *X server* (which provides a basis for graphical user interfaces) and *gdm-binary* itself (which launches sessions), so the only sensitive information is probably just your username(s).

The best way would be to open those logs in `/var/log/gdm` as root and check for yourself.

Comment: But why of X server? /var/log/Xorg.* are X server logs.